# How to set minDate in bootstrap3 datepicker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

$("#txtdatefrom").datepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',minDate: moment(),todayHighlight: true})

Comment: What datepicker are you using? Can you link it? Anyway see how to create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1999:2012',
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate: new Date(1999, 10 - 1, 25),
        maxDate: '+30Y',
        inline: true
    });
});
```